# Sort scoreboard by name and score using ruby

Tags: ruby, libgosu

i have a text file that consists of these:

```
player1
10
player2
13
player3
60
```

These are the player name and score. For example, the score for player 1 is 10 and the score for player 2 is 13 and so on. I want to sort the text file by score. For example:

```
player3 60
player2 13
player1 10
```

Comment: You can't sort a file right away. You have to read the text file and parse the name-score pairs into a sortable data structure like an array. You probably already tried something yourself. Show your attempts, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read the file into an array, do some manipulation, then write back to file.
Assuming the source file contains pairs of rows as showed..

First read the lines of the file into an array, [File#readlines](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/IO.html#method-i-readlines) (note, `chomp: true` for stripping `"\n"`).

```
data = File.readlines('score.txt', chomp: true)
#=> ["player1", "10", "player2", "13", "player3", "60"]
```

Once you have your array, group every two elements([Enumerable#each_slice](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice)) and sort by the second element considered as an integer (`.to_i`) ([Enumerable#sort_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by)). Note the `-` sign for reversing the order of sorting. As last operation `map` ([Enumerable#map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map)) to `join` the pair of elements in the nested array ([Array#join](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-join)):

```
score_sorted = data.each_slice(2).sort_by { |_, score| -score.to_i}.map{ |ary| ary.join(' ') }
#=> ["player3 60", "player2 13", "player1 10"]
```

Finally, write the array back to file ([File#open](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/IO.html#method-c-open)):

```
File.open("score_sorted.txt", "w+") { |f| f.puts score_sorted }
```

Comment: i used the code from your help `score_sorted = data.each_slice(2).sort_by { |_, score| -score.to_i}.map{ |ary| ary.join(' ') }`, but the output is ["player1", "10", "player2", "13", "player3", "60"] instead of ["player3 60", "player2 13", "player1 10"], by the way the sorting works

Answer (score 0):

The base implementation of this case may be something like this:

```rb
def main

  file = File.new("score.txt", "r")
  players = Array.new
  score = Array.new
  number_regex = /\A[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+\Z/

  file.each_line do |line|
    if(line.match(number_regex))
      score << line.delete(" \t\r\n")
    else
      players << line.delete(" \t\r\n")
    end
  end

  file.close

  result = Hash.new
  i = 0

  while i < players.length
    result[players[i]] = score[i]
    i += 1
  end

  print_score(result)

end

def print_score(hash)
  hash.each do |key,value|
    puts key + ": " + value
  end
end

main
```

But, I warn !!! This is just a basic implementation. This solution has some side effects, for example, if the data sequence of the data is broken, this algorithm will stop working.

```
player1
10
player2
player3
60
```

To implement a fully working solution, you need to check the next line when reading each line and validate it for the content of the desired values. If the sequence is broken, and after the value of "playerN" the number of points scored does not go, then consider in this case their absence as 0.
In general, creating a holistic solution in this case is not an easy task. And in order to choose the optimal solution, in fact, you did not provide enough data. Where does the .txt account is recorded from? Is it possible to change the source of the recording? And so on